# Creating dojox/app Views Programmatically without HTML

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am thinking of making a web app and was contemplating using dojox/app to do it.

I would prefer to use a more programmatic approach to dojo but it seems dojox/app is mostly declarative.

After some searching I found an archive basically asking the same question I have
http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Questions-about-dojox-app-design-td3988709.html

> Hay guys, 
>   I've been looking at the livedocs for dojox.app and while it seems quite cool I >have to say some stuff isn't clear to me.
>
> Specifically, is the "template" property of views - specifying an html file - a >must or optional?

This was in 2012.

Since then I have found the customeApp test in the examples in the documentation which seems to show basic  programmatic views in dojox/app however I am having some difficulty understanding it.

I would like to create the different views of my app like this

```
require([
  "dojo/dom",
  "dojo/ready",
  "dojox/mobile/Heading",
  "dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton"
], function(dom, ready, Heading, ToolBarButton){
  ready(function(){
    var heading = new Heading({
      id: "viewHeading",
      label: "World Clock"
    });
    heading.addChild(new ToolBarButton({label:"Edit"}));
    var tb = new ToolBarButton({
      icon:"mblDomButtonWhitePlus",
      style:"float:right;"
    });
    tb.on("click", function(){ console.log('+ was clicked'); });
    heading.addChild(tb);
    heading.placeAt(document.body);
    heading.startup();
  });
});
```

but I can only find examples like this

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading" data-dojo-props='label:"World Clock"'>
  <span data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton">Edit</span>
  <span data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton"
        data-dojo-props='icon:"mblDomButtonWhitePlus"'
        style="float:right;" onclick="console.log('+ was clicked')"></span>
</div>
```

Is there a way to go about this programmatically or somewhere I can find some clarification on whats happening here https://github.com/dmachi/dojox_application/tree/master/tests/customApp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely. I have been creating them programmatically for a long time and believe it is far superior way than templating. Difficulty in tackling a framework is knowing keywords to search for. Your answer, I believe, can be found by learning Dojo WidgetBase, and anything else that uses the word "Widget".

Good start is here http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/writingWidgets.html . To successfully work with Dojo Widgets you will also need:

- concept of a LifeCycle http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/_WidgetBase.html#id5. Lifecycle injection points will allow you to modify DOM tree of the template using JavaScript native API so you do not have to use *data-dojo* in attributes all over. You will capture nodes as private class properties during *buildRendering* phase so you can apply constructor parameters to them passed during instantiation in the parent. Finally, you will return the final DOM in *postCreate()* or *startup()*, depending on whether you need to specially handle child components or not.
- concept of Evented http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/Evented.html . This is what you need to do *widgetInstance.on("someEvent", eventHandler)* programmatically

Only custom attribute I use within an HTML tags of templateString is *data-dojo-attach-point* and *data-dojo-attach-event*. These are very convenient, saving lots of time and makes data binding less bug prone, to automatically connect widget's class properties with values in the tag. Although you can do those programmatically too with innerHTML, the amount of tedious boilerplate code in my opinion is not worth the effort.

Go through that tutorial and if by end you do not understand something do let me know and I will elaborate (I am not the type who just sends askers away on a link and not bother elaborate on the material).